# Прием платежей в приложении Android

Tags: java, android, платежи

у меня возник такой вопрос.
Допустим, есть Android приложение , в нем пользователь должен иметь возможность совершать покупки через qiwi, яндекс деньги, карту и т.д,  также должна быть возможность выплаты пользователю денег на карту ,qiwi, яндекс и т.д.
Отсюда вопрос, как принимать платежи в приложении и выплачивать деньги пользователю?
Может, для этого есть какие-нибудь сервисы или sdk?
Что посоветуете ?

Comment: все перечисленные вами платежные системы имеют или SDK или сервисы для приема и отправки платежей

Answer (score 3):

SDK явно не может существовать, поскольку, работая с финансами, программный код (ваш код) должен пройти кучу проверок, инстанций чтоб получить лицензию ну например PCI DSS (Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard)

Что остается? Технология OAuth. Это такая прослойка которая перекладывает всю ответственность за реальные действия на сторонние сервисы. От программного кода только требуется попросить пользователя авторизоваться (а значит программа получит OAuth токен) и дальше по этому токену обращаться к PayPal примерно так:

- Пользователь с таким-то токеном хочет заплатить 10 денег.
- Щас подумаю. Да, давал такой токен. Дам тебе знать когда закончу транзакцию
- ок, жду
- транзакция обработана результат: принято (или отказано). Можешь выдать пользователю платный контент он заплатил все по нормально.

---

Обычно OAuth это про веб-ресурс. Открываем браузер с сайтом PayPal и так далее. В мобильном мире, насколько мне известно, для этих целей может быть использовано специализированное мобильное приложение если оно есть.